# React JS triggering re-render when props sorted

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component for a list of data comprised of two sub components

```
<List>
   <SortingAndFiltering data={this.state.data}/>
   <RowsDisplay data={this.state.data}/>
</List>
```

One subcomponent handles sorts and filters and the other renders the actual bulk of the data.

When I perform a sort on the props.data inside SortingAndFiltering the event isn't propagated up the chain.

Whats the correct way to signal that a consumer of a prop has made a change to this prop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React doesn’t do *two-way data bindings* by default and for good reasons.

However, there is an add-on called `ReactLink` that could be of use: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html

If you are using Backbone as data models, there are mixins that provide listeners for model changes that can re-render the app when signals are received from anywhere in the hierarchy.

To dig deeper regarding unidirectional data flow, I recommend this video that explains the Flux concept used by Facebook: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/flux-overview.html

Comment: Cool that makes a lot of sense, basically if you are performing an action at a leaf pass that change as an action back to the parent to perform the data change

Comment: @David Hi, could you help to give a look at my question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926833/how-to-identify-component-in-flux-of-react

Comment: @David Im pretty new to FLUX, kinda stuck at how to structure the app.

Answer (score 0):

checkout http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html step 5,which is similar to yours.