# How to identify component in FLUX of React

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am pretty new to FLUX, so I started with the TODO example on their website:
https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html

In the [Listening to Changes with a Controller-View](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html#listening-to-changes-with-a-controller-view) part:

There is on event binding in TodoApp:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    TodoStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
}
```

and `this._onChange` is like:

```
 _onChange: function() {
    this.setState(getTodoState());
}
```

The addChangeListener from TodoStore is like:

```
addChangeListener: function(callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
}
```

What confused me here is:

It seems that the store just simply register that `_onChange()`, but **how does the TodoStore know whose _onChange() need to be called if there are multiple TodoApps rendered on the page.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TodoStore simply emits the event and every component that is listening to that store will update. So if you have two `TodoApp`s on page, both will update.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I am too new to JS, one question related to this answer is: in that _onChange, the function body is this.setState(getTodoState()); but this function is actually called inside TodoStore's addChangeListener, I wonder how TodoStore knows what that "this" is?

Comment: getTodoState() should just return an object for setState to consume so the store doesn't need to know about the "this" of the component. Like this.setState({some: 'data'});

Comment: Thanks, I guess what I am more concerned is: where that "this._setState" get called. From the code, it seems get called inside TodoStore, in that context, the this could be either WINDOW or the store, but how can "this" be the TodoApp?

Comment: "this.setState" gets called in component? "this" refers to the instance of the component. Let me know if you're talking about something other than the "this.setState" from inside the "_onChange" function of the component